# MVC5 Parial View with model property

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, binding, model, partial-views

I want to create partial view which will display property of the model.
Now I have something like this:

```
<div class="form-group"> 
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Property, new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
  <div class="col-md-10">
    @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Property, new { @class = "form-control" }) 
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Property)
  </div>
</div>
```

I would like to have this as a separate control (partial view) which would be binded with the model property.

I need to add users additiona operarion on this data (buttons, sliders, etc), but still I would need it to be properly binded to original data and that Label and validation would still work.

Model is full of this properties which are:

```
<nullable>int
```

so it would be nice to have this partial view to maintain clear code.

I'm playing with partial views but without much success for the moment.

EDIT

I dont want to pass whole model, because in the partial view I would need to take care of all of the properties and I have around 300 of them, so to edit all of them I need exactly this same code with js. So in view where I take care of the model, for each property I would use this partial view.

Answer (score 0):

you should pass the model of main view to partial view and show your models and all view

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so you want to create a partial for a bunch of items.

Not sure if you using razor of not but you can do this

```
     @foreach(var item in Model.items)
    {
      Html.RenderPartial("_PartialView", item);
    }
```

This would load a partial for every item you want.